# xcode running well on simulator but when deploy to ios 6 encounter error

Tags: ios, xcode

2012-10-08 14:48:14.579 sageby[2716:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SBJsonParser errorTrace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fda4660'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x352412a3 0x34a1397f 0x35244e07 0x35243531 0x3519af68 0x12932f 0x1293a7 0x12cda3 0x12c9b1 0x12c753 0x12aac7 0x12e567 0x12eac3 0x3a26bef5 0x3a1ab9f1 0x3a1ab90d 0x384ba5df 0x384b9ccb 0x384e2133 0x3518774d 0x384e2593 0x3844615d 0x35216683 0x35215ee9 0x35214cb7 0x35187ebd 0x35187d49 0x35ef02eb 0x37dcd301 0xaaaf1 0x39e0cb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

---

```
//MBProgressHUD 
    MBProgressHUD *hud=[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText=@"Accessing account..";
    hud.labelFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:14];


            //URL GETTING
            NSString *phpfile=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://dev.xxxx.com/pxxx/Module_MyPxxx/json_xxxx_xxx_info.php"];
            NSString *param_str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"email=%@", mydelegate.overall_email];
            NSString *receivedDataAsString=[mydelegate phpConnection:param_str :phpfile];

            SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
            NSError *error=nil;
            self.dic_user_info=[[parser objectWithString:receivedDataAsString error:&error]objectAtIndex:0];
            if(error)
            {
                NSLog(@"JSON Parser error! Reason: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }



            //URL GETTING
            phpfile=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://dev.xxx.com/pxxx/Module_MyPxxx/json_get_xxx_xxx_pxxx.php"];
            param_str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"email=%@", mydelegate.overall_email];
            receivedDataAsString=[mydelegate phpConnection:param_str :phpfile];

            parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
            error=nil;
            self.array_polls=[parser objectWithString:receivedDataAsString error:&error];
            if(error)
            {
                NSLog(@"JSON Parser error! Reason: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: can you show some of the code near where this error is coming from?  Where are you calling "`errorTrace`"??

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
        return retVal;
    }

}

Comment: you have to post your codes instead of just posting the error output. But apparently, the `SBJsonParser` object / variable is `null`.

Comment: it works fine with xcode simulator but not when deployed on ios 6

Answer (score 0):

hi i'm the developer of the application.

The problem is that running on Xcode 4.5 is correct but just running on iphone device it wont work..

Comment: The iphone device has been updated to iOS6. Could there be some mismatch between iOS6 and iphone simulator x4.5?  Thanks for help!